# Restore a mongo DB from a compose.io backup?

Tags: mongodb, restore, compose-db

If you download a compose.io backup of a mongodb instance and uncompress the .tar file you end up with `.ns` and extensions that are single digits.  How do you restore the db from these?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The .ns .0 .1 etc. files are the data files themselves.

This the raw db you can `mongodump` those files and then mongorestore as always:

[This solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/439658/is-it-possible-to-recover-mongodb-databases-from-ns-and-0-1-files) would work pre mongo 3.0, but --dbpath is no longer supported 
by `mongodump`.

### Mongo 3.0 Solution:

1. Run `mongod --dbpath ./` from the directory with the extracted download with the `.ns` files.
2. Run `mongodump -d [DBNAME] -o  [DIR TO DUMP TO]`  ...options are not required.
3. Proceed with a mongorestore as normal

Comment: I've got a post here explaining how to do this in detail: https://dhariri.com/posts/570275fed1befa596a80bba2

Comment: So what would be the solution for MongoDB 3.x?

Comment: @user3072843 The above solution worked for Mongo 3.4.